# Fakepath issue with AJAX/PHP submit

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im trying to build a simple PHP update record that uses AJAX to submit information, my form inserts my records correctly only it prepends `C:\fakepath\` to my image file name?

Ive never seen this before - has anybody an idea on how to remove this?

Comment: New browsers do this for security reasons (so the receiving web site doesn't know where the file was located on the user's computer). There's nothing you can do to change it; there should be no need, though - just cut away the file name if you need it

Comment: @Pekka웃 that should be an answer

Comment: @Pekka웃 Agreed, that's a good answer. Here's further documentation: http://davidwalsh.name/fakepath